# Excel VBA Date Replacement

Tags: vba, excel, date, excel-2010

I have some dates in cells as ISO standard (YYYY/MM/DD) but I'm being asked to change it to DD MMMMMMMM YYYY e.g. 1 January 2018.

There are multiple dates in a single cell, I've checked a few sites and unable to find some VBA I can use to search for YYYY/MM/DD format and change to DD MMMMMMMM YYYY.

Would any one know some VBA / Links which can help change all the dates in one rather than a manual effort.

[[image: Example of current status and desired output]]

Currently I've tried but my VBA is below novice at best so unable to reverse engineer the below solutions.
https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/6-ways-to-fix-dates-formatted-as-text-in-excel

https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/.../excel.../93919-search-and-replace-date-with-vba

https://stackoverflow.com/.../find-replace-macro-that-properly-formats-a-date-cell

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EIyJ2TGgqQMJ:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_2007/find-and-replace-date-in-vba-keeping-the-format/64377177-9b0f-4118-81ed-49d8f9ddc8f4+&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

EDIT:
Output with Karthick's solution below. The only problem is the first date is changed but the Line breaks from ALT+Enter are lost and formatting goes iffy.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZFa3.jpg)

Comment: can you show the cell data?

Comment: are cell values constants or come from formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below formula

```
=TEXT(LEFT(C2,10),"DD MMMMMMMM YYYY")&MID(C2,11,LEN(C2))
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**EDIT**

Please use the vba code to get your desired result.

```
Sub test()
    Dim a, b As String
    Dim str1, str2 As Long
    a = Range("C2").Value
    str1 = Split(a, Chr(10))
    str2 = UBound(str1)
    For i = 0 To str2
        b = b & Format(Left(str1(i), 10), "DD MMMM YYYY") & Mid(str1(i), 11, Len(str1(i))) & Chr(10)
    Next i
    Range("D2").Value = b
End Sub
```

**VBA OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: there are multiple dates in one cell, also how you want to replace with formulas?

Comment: This is a valid answer, your example shows date values in the text string on the first 10 characters. A second date string should also be reoccuring at a specified place in the string. Replace should be easy after example from Karthick....just copy paste outcome? Otherwise use vba.

Comment: Hi Karthick, I tried your suggestion and it replaces the first date in line but then the formatting for the cell is broken and all collapses onto a single line and losses the line breaks from Alt+Enter.

Comment: set the wrap text

Comment: Thank you very much Karthick

Comment: @KanekiByte, Welcome always

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions will be your friend for something like this. The following will match every numerical date with a `/` as the separator. It will then find each match and replace with the format as specified by the `DateFormat` variable. Update the `With ActiveSheet` to the name of your sheet to declare it explicitly and you may need to modify the `rng` variable for your own range

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ConvertDateFormat()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim RegExp As Object: Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Dim DateFormat As String
    Dim c, d

    DateFormat = "DD MMMM YYYY"

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 3))
    End With

    With RegExp
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(\d{2,4}(\/|(?=\s)|\d$)){3}"

        For Each c In rng
            If .test(c) Then
                For Each d In .Execute(c.Value2)
                    c.Value2 = Replace(c.Value2, d, Format(d.Value, DateFormat))
                Next d
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, I'll give this a shot to see if I can get it working.